# Business mathematics

Tags: calculus, economics

The demand function for a good is given as $$P = 50 - 2Q$$

1. Write down expressions for the TR and MR functions.
2. Find and classify the type of the point price elasticity at price $P = 10$
3. Calculate the output at which TR is a maximum, and use
   $\hspace{0.4cm}$ second order
   conditions to confirm that it is maximum.
4. Confirm that marginal revenue is zero at maximum point.

Comment: Maybe TR, MR are common abbreviations in business mathematics (I've no idea), but you should show some self work in this, anyway.

Comment: @DonAntonio A quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=TR%2C+MR+demand&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab) helps.

Comment: I think it has a print error  for derivative dTR/dQ

Comment: @callculus Oh, I'm not interested at all...

Answer (score 1):

$ TR = P×Q \Rightarrow TR=(50−2Q)Q=50Q-2Q^2$ 


The marginal revenue function is the first derivative of the total revenue function


$MR=50-4Q$


When the derivative of TR=0 in that point it reachs its maximum value($Q=\frac{50}{4}$)


The Price elasticity($e_p=\frac{P_o}{Q_o}*Q(P_o)'$) 
$e_p=\frac{10}{20}*0.5=1/4=0.25$ which means  Relatively Inelastic